# moveit: How to change the initial pose for robot in Rviz?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used 'moveit_setup_assitant' to config my robot, but I cannot find where can I set the robot's initial pose. The question is that the robot's initial pose in simulation environment is not the same as the one in real world. So is there any way to change the initial pose when I launch the robot in 'demo.launch'?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375942/moveit:-how-to-change-the-initial-pose-for-robot-in-rviz?/) by [xiaozhenghong](https://answers.ros.org/users/72341/xiaozhenghong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-04-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-12**:
I've updated the title to mention MoveIt, as it would appear that's the context in which you asked this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add an entry to `fake_controllers.yaml` referencing the named poses like [this](https://github.com/ros-planning/panda_moveit_config/blob/melodic-devel/config/fake_controllers.yaml):

```
initial:
  - group: panda_arm
    pose: ready
  - group: hand
    pose: open
```

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xiaozhenghong](https://answers.ros.org/users/72341/xiaozhenghong/) on 2021-04-12**:
thx for your answering! The method works will in the fake_controllers.yaml, but I use ros_controller.yaml as controllers of my robot(in order to get way points from planning, I set fake_execution in demo.launch to be false). And I found the method will not work in this controller file.

```
    controller_list:
  - name: left_manipulator_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: True
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - ljoint1
      - ljoint2
      - ljoint3
      - ljoint4
      - ljoint5
      - ljoint6
      - ljoint7
  - name: right_manipulator_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: True
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - rjoint1
      - rjoint2
      - rjoint3
      - rjoint4
      - rjoint5
      - rjoint6
      - rjoint7
initial:
  - group: left_manipulator
    pose: left_original
```

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-04-12**:
The position of your real-world robot is determined by reality, not the setting in your YAML. If you want the robot to move to a certain pose, you should plan and execute a motion to it.

Also, consider using `your_moveit_config_planning_execution.launch` instead of `demo.launch` if you don't use the fake controllers.

**Comment by [xiaozhenghong](https://answers.ros.org/users/72341/xiaozhenghong/) on 2021-04-12**:
Ok, thx again!